# Random movement angular

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, rxjs, observable

I'm currently working on a game which is based on a svg canvas as shown

[image]

and what I'm trying to do now is to allow the ball to move at random once the game starts, but I'm having difficulties coding out the random movement.

```
function createBall() {
    const svg = document.getElementById("canvas")!,  
        ball = new Elem(svg, 'circle')     #create the ball
            .attr("cx",300).attr("cy",300)
            .attr("r",8)
            .attr('fill','grey');

    Observable.interval(10).takeUntil(Observable.interval(4000))   #10 milliseconds until 4000 milliseconds
        .subscribe( () => ball.attr("cx", 2 + Number(ball.attr("cx"))));  #I'm having issue here when i subscribe as i can only allow the ball to move to the right at the moment, aside from being random
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need a constant velocity towards a certain direction in x and y coordinates.

My suggestion would be to create two random integer values for x_velocity and y_velocity. You could try to use Math.random() and Math.floor():

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() + min) * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Then you will need to determine the direction, if it is negative (go left) or positive (go right):

```
function getDirection() {
    return this.getRandomInt(0, 2) === 0? -1 : 1; 
}
```

Use these two functions to set your `x_velocity` and `y_velocity`. The ball should now be able to go to the left, right, up, or down:

```
directionX = this.getDirection();
directionY = this.getDirection();
x_velocity = directionX * this.getRandomInt(1,8); // the number will be between -8 and 8 excluding 0
y_velocity = directionY * this.getRandomInt(1,8); // same here

Observable.interval(10).takeUntil(Observable.interval(4000))   
    .subscribe( () => {
        ball.attr("cx", x_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cx"))); // the ball should go towards the left or the right
        ball.attr("cy", y_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cy"))); // the ball should go up or down
    );
```

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: hi, yes it starts moving at random but only between the direction of west and north west. However, if i were to add getRandomInt(1,8) + x_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cx")), the same with + y_velocity at the subscribe statement, the ball is able to move in all directions except that it has some strange "vibration" like movement on it.

Comment: Did you have that problem when it was set as 2? I'm wondering if the vibration is due to the interval being set as 10. Could you try testing it with getRandomInt(1,2)?

Comment: apparently reducing it to (1,2) slows down the speed. But there is still some vibration. But without adding getRandomInt(1,2) + x_velocity and getRandomInt(1,2) + y_velocity in the subscribe statement, the ball doesn't move in all directions except within northwest.

Comment: Did the vibration happen with `ball.attr("cx", 2 + Number(ball.attr("cx")))`?

Comment: no. Sorry I'm afraid I'm not being clear. x_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cx") and y_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cy") works fine as suggested. But its only moving northwest with a slight shift. It's when i tried adding getRandomInt(1,8) + x_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cx")) and getRandomInt(1,8) + y_velocity + Number(ball.attr("cy")), the ball moves in all directions, except it has a vibration to it and sloppy movement.

Comment: No, I apologize, I think I made a mistake in the getDirection() function. The max value should be 2 and not 1. I'll update the answer! 

`this.getRandomInt(0, 2) === 0? -1 : 1; `

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: hi, sorry for asking but is there a reason for the ball only moving between the northwest and southeast direction only now when i tried refreshing the page multiple times. It seems like the coordinates is not adding up to these missing directions.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that the `direction` value is always the same for both x and y. X and Y would always be positive or negative together which means that it would always be in the northwest or southeast direction. I will update the solution to solve this issue.

Added: 
`directionX = this.getDirection();`
`directionY = this.getDirection();`